# Image Data Loss from Python Server to Android Client (Endian Issue??)

Tags: java, python, android, tcp, endianness

I am needing help transferring a PNG image via TCP from my raspberry pi (python) to my android application (java). I have spent almost two weeks trying to understand and solve this problem, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have set up a client-server architecture such that my raspberry pi 3 records audio, performs some analysis on it, and then sends the data (via TCP) to the android app to display on the app screen. The recording and analysis is done and I am able to make the connection and transfer string data that displays on the app with no problem. However, I have been unsuccessful in transferring an image from rpi to android app. So basically, the image is stored on the rpi and I an attempting to transfer the image to the app to display it.

**Current Implementation:**

**On rpi (python)**: Like I said, sending strings and displaying them on the android app is done without any problem. When I am sending the image portion of the audio analysis, I send a string first that says "?start" so that the android side knows that an image instead of a string is about to be sent (and will wait to update the GUI until it receives the entire image). Then, I open the image stored on rpi and read the entire image as a byte array (typically about 40-50k bytes). I get the length of the byte array and send that as a string to android app. Finally, I send the byte array to the android and it waits for an OK message from the app. All of this works without reporting any errors.

**On android app (java)**: When the app receives the "?start" string, it then uses a Buffered Reader (which is what I used to read the string data I had transferred to the app successfully earlier) to read the size of the image byte array. Then, I create a buffer, `msg_buff`, to read in at most 1024 bytes at a time while `baos` will hold the entire byte array of the image. In the infinite while loop, I have a DataInputStream, called `in`, read bytes into `msg_buff` and returns the number of bytes read. Then, I add the contents of `msg_buff` into `baos`. Once the bytes read from `in` is -1 or the `img_offset` (which is just the total number of bytes read) is greater than or equal to the size of the image bytes array, the while loop is broken. Then, I would attempt to save the image to android internal storage and then load it later to an `ImageView` to display it. This code does successfully read in the bytes until there are around 2000-3000 bytes left to be read and then it seems to freeze on the `int bytes_read = in.read(msg_buff, 0, byte_size)` line. I have not been able to get past that point so I do not know if saving the image to internal storage and then loading it to `ImageView` that way will work either. **I believe it is freezing on this line because some bytes are being lost or not sent from python to java. Does anyone know how I can resolve this?**

The code that reads the image data from the python server is in the `run()` method.

**TCPClient.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;


public class TcpClient {

    public static final String SERVER_IP = myIPAddress; //your computer IP address

    public static final int SERVER_PORT = myPortNumber;

    // message to send to the server

    private String mServerMessage;

    // sends message received notifications

    private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;

    // while this is true, the server will continue running

    private boolean mRun = false;

    // used to send messages

    private PrintWriter mBufferOut;

    // used to read messages from the server

    private BufferedReader mBufferIn;



    /**

     * Constructor of the class. OnMessagedReceived listens for the messages received from server

     */

    public TcpClient(OnMessageReceived listener) {

        mMessageListener = listener;

    }


    /**

     * Sends the message entered by client to the server

     *

     * @param message text entered by client

     */

    public void sendMessage(String message) {

        if (mBufferOut != null && !mBufferOut.checkError()) {

            mBufferOut.println(message);

            mBufferOut.flush();

        }

    }



    /**

     * Close the connection and release the members

     */

    public void stopClient() {

        Log.i("Debug", "stopClient");

        mRun = false;

        if (mBufferOut != null) {

            mBufferOut.flush();

            mBufferOut.close();

        }

        mMessageListener = null;

        mBufferIn = null;

        mBufferOut = null;

        mServerMessage = null;

    }

    public void run() {

        mRun = true;

        try {

            //here you must put your computer's IP address.

            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

            Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");

            //create a socket to make the connection with the server

            Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVER_PORT);

            try {

                InputStream sin = socket.getInputStream();
                OutputStream sout = socket.getOutputStream();
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(sin);
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();


                mBufferIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));


                //in this while the client listens for the messages sent by the server

                while (mRun) {


                    mServerMessage = mBufferIn.readLine();

                    if (mServerMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {

                        //Check if data is image
                        if(mServerMessage.equals("?start"))
                        {
                            mServerMessage = mBufferIn.readLine();

                            String fileName = "";

                            if(mServerMessage.equals("signal"))
                            {
                                fileName = "signal.jpeg";
                            }
                            else if(mServerMessage.equals("spec"))
                            {
                                fileName = "spec.jpeg";
                            }

                            // Get length of image byte array
                            int size = Integer.parseInt(mBufferIn.readLine());
                            Log.i("Debug:", "image message size: "+size);


                            // Create buffers
                            byte[] msg_buff = new byte[1024];
                            //byte[] img_buff = new byte[size];
                            int img_offset = 0;

                            while(true){
                                int byte_size = msg_buff.length;
                                int bytes_read = in.read(msg_buff, 0, byte_size);
                                Log.i("Debug:", "image message bytes:" + bytes_read);

                                if(bytes_read == -1){
                                    break;
                                }

                                //copy bytes into img_buff
                                //System.arraycopy(msg_buff, 0, img_buff, img_offset, bytes_read);
                                baos.write(msg_buff, 0, bytes_read);

                                img_offset += bytes_read;

                                Log.i("Debug:", "image message bytes read:"+img_offset);

                                if( img_offset >= size)
                                {
                                    break;
                                }

                            }

                            try{

                                byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

                                ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);

                                ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(ApplicationContextProvider.getContext());
                                File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                File mypath = new File(directory, fileName);

                                //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img_buff, 0, img_buff.length);
                                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bais);

                                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);

                                //Use compress method on Bitmap object to write image to OutputStream
                                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);

                                fos.flush();
                                fos.close();

                                //Send OK
                                byte[] OK = new byte[] {0x4F, 0x4B};
                                sout.write(OK);

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.i("Debug:", "image message" +e);
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }


                        }

                        //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class

                        mMessageListener.messageReceived(mServerMessage);
                    }

                }

                Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + mServerMessage + "'");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);

            } finally {

                //the socket must be closed. It is not possible to reconnect to this socket

                // after it is closed, which means a new socket instance has to be created.

                socket.close();

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);

        }

    }

    //Declare the interface. The method messageReceived(String message) must be implemented in the MainActivity

    //class in asynckTask doInBackground

    public interface OnMessageReceived {

        void messageReceived(String message);

    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TcpClient mTcpClient;
    private TextView dbView;
    private TextView roomView;
    private TextView classView;
    private TextView statusView;
    private TextView timeView;
    private ImageView signalView;
    private ImageView specView;
    private Button getAnalysis;
    private Button disconnect;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getAnalysis = findViewById(R.id.get_analysis);
        dbView = findViewById(R.id.db_level);
        roomView = findViewById(R.id.RoomsValues);
        classView = findViewById(R.id.ClassValues);
        timeView = findViewById(R.id.timeStamp);
        signalView = findViewById(R.id.audioPic);
        specView = findViewById(R.id.specPic);
        statusView = findViewById(R.id.status);
        disconnect = findViewById(R.id.disconnect);


        getAnalysis.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                statusView.setText("Connecting to Auris...\nRoom analytics will arrive shortly.");
                new ConnectTask().execute("");
            }
        });



        disconnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                mTcpClient.stopClient();
                statusView.setText("Disconnected from Auris.\nReconnect to receive room analysis updates.");

            }
        });



    }

    public class ConnectTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, TcpClient> {
        @Override
        protected TcpClient doInBackground(String... message) {
            //we create a TCPClient object and
            mTcpClient = new TcpClient(new TcpClient.OnMessageReceived() {
                @Override
                //here the messageReceived method is implemented
                public void messageReceived(String message) {
                    //this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                    publishProgress(message);
                    Log.i("Debug","Input message: " + message);
                }
            });
            //statusView.setText("Get analysis from Auris as it is collected.");
            mTcpClient.run();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            //Store string of values sent from Auris device
            String str = values[0];

            //if data starts with +, then it is the string data
            if(str.startsWith("+"))
            {
                //Split values around spaces
                /*
                    Values in data indices
                        0-8 are room log likelihoods
                        9-12 are class log likelihoods
                        13 is dbA level
                        14 is room model best matched
                        15 is class model best matched

                */
                // Remove +
                str = str.substring(1);
                String data[]= str.split(" ");
                String roomData = "";
                String classData = "";
                String status;

                for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
                {
                    roomData = roomData.concat(data[i]);
                    roomData = roomData.concat("\n");

                }

                roomView.setText(roomData);

                for(int i = 9; i < 13; i++)
                {
                    classData = classData.concat(data[i]);
                    classData = classData.concat("\n");
                }

                classView.setText(classData);

                dbView.setText(data[13]);
                status = "The room most closely matches " + data[14] + " room model & " + data[15] + " class model.";
                statusView.setText(status);
            }

            else if (str.startsWith("TIME"))
            {
                // Remove "TIME"
                str.substring(4);
                String message = "This room profile represents the room at " + str + ".";
                timeView.setText(message);
            }

            else
            {
                try {
                    String fileName = "";

                    if(str.equals("signal"))
                    {
                        fileName = "signal.jpeg";
                    }
                    else if(str.equals("spec"))
                    {
                        fileName = "spec.jpeg";
                    }

                    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(ApplicationContextProvider.getContext());
                    File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    File file = new File(directory, fileName);
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file));
                    signalView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


            Log.i("onProgressUpdate",values[0]);
        }
    }

}
```

**Python Code to send Image Data:**

```
def send_image_to_byte_array(image_file, conn, label):
    with open(image_file, "rb") as imageFile:
        content = imageFile.read()
        conn.sendall("?start\n".encode('utf-8'))
        conn.sendall(label.encode('utf-8'))
        size = len(content)
        strSize = str(size) + "\n"
        conn.sendall(strSize.encode('utf-8'))
        conn.sendall(content)
```

From what I can tell, not all of the bytes of the image are successfully being sent from the rpi to the android app. There is data loss which causes the android app to hang on the `int bytes_read = in.read(msg_buff, 0, byte_size);` line in the `run()` method of **TCPClient.java**. From reading different posts, it seems that using **struct.unpack/pack** fixes this problem when transferring an image from python to python, but I do not know how to implement struct.unpack in java or if I can just use some input stream. I am also not sure what would be the best approach to using struct.pack in python. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**
I believe the problem is the endianess. From what I have read, raspberry pi is little endian and java is big endian. So, when I read the image that was saved to raspberry pi and try to transmit it to java from python, these issues are occurring. Does anyone know how I can change the endianness of java from big to little or some other way to fix this problem?

Comment: Recommend you run the app in an emulator so you can tcpdump/wireshark it easily, then post the .pcap here.

Comment: @greeble31 even though I was able to make a connection between my rpi and android app and send data, my android does not show up in wireshark. I made an edit that I think the problem has to do with endianness of rpi vs java, do you know how I can solve that problem?

Comment: "android does not show up in wireshark" - that doesn't sound right; perhaps there is a misconfiguration. I think you are barking up the wrong tree with 'struct.pack' and the endianness theory. Although these can cause other issues, it shouldn't cause this particular problem, b/c you are transmitting the size as a string.

Comment: I'm sure its just some little thing we're missing. To troubleshoot, you might try sending a known payload (say, a string of a's), in place of your image. And see if the string length has any bearing on the problem.

Comment: @greeble31 honestly I'm grasping at anything because I've been working on this one problem for 80+ hours (about 2 weeks) now with no progress. I was thinking the endianness may be an issue since python saves the image to rpi (in little endian) and then python reads the contents of this saved image as a byte array that is then read in java which would want to read it in big endian. I know endianness has to do with the order in which bytes are read so maybe the bytes need to be reversed? but when I used the reverse() function, it didn't fix the issue

Comment: @greeble31 I will try that

Comment: Right, well that's part of programming. When you run into a difficult problem, you have to whittle away at it, in order to gain an understand of exactly which parts are working the way you expect, and which aren't. The reason I don't think endianness is a problem is because you're just dealing with a byte array (string). Sure, you could have endianness problems _within_ the array, but you're not there yet; you haven't managed to transmit the entire array.

Comment: The only reason `in.read()` would block is because it's waiting on more data. That means the pi didn't send as much as it was expecting. It's not clear why. But if you replace your "unknown" image data with "known" data, then you can dump it on the Java side and compare it to what you expected. For instance, if you make the data a long string of "a's" terminated with a single "b", it becomes easier to keep your place as you debug.

Comment: @greeble31 okay thank you that makes sense. Just to clarify, would I send the string of a's terminated by a b as a string or a byte array?

Comment: In Python 2.X? I think they're pretty much the same thing. You can do a `.encode()` just to be sure.

Comment: @greeble31 I used the same code except I replaced imageFile.read() in the python code with b'aaaaaaab'. On the java side, it successfully read the size as 8 but then froze on the in.read() line

Comment: May have forgotten the socket `.flush()` call on the pi side.

Comment: @greeble31 there doesn't seem to be a .flush() method to call for Socket class in python. I am also sending it via TCP and from what I've read, there is no way to flush it since it's a stream

Comment: Yes, sorry for shooting from the hip there. I just took a closer look at your code and I think you may be trying to read it out from under your `BufferedReader`. That is, 'aaaaaaab' probably isn't returned from `in.read()` because `mBufferIn` already snarfed it off the line. Try just using `mBufferIn.read()` instead. (You're probably losing the beginning 2000-3000 bytes of the data, not the last.)

Comment: @greeble31 Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work either. I also tried sending the size from python to java as bytes but java froze when trying to read that as well.

Comment: Hmm. Fact is, I can't see how that _couldn't_ be the problem. If you want to force the issue, just send several thousand c's after you send the 'aaaaaaab'. That'll use up all the socket buffers, and should force `read()` to return something interesting, whether its a's or c's.

Comment: @greeble31 okay, I will give it a try! Just to make sure I am understanding correctly, you were saying to just replace the int size = Integer.parseInt(mBufferIn.readLine()); line with int size = mBufferIn.read(); and leave everything else the same on the java side?

Comment: No, sorry, I was unclear. Once you give your socket's `InputStream` to the `BufferedReader` (via the constructor), don't use that `InputStream` for anything else. Access all of the socket's input data via the `BufferedReader`. What I meant was, take your original code, and replace the `in.read(msg_buf, 0, buf_size)` with `mBufferIn.read(msg_buf, 0, buf_size)`.

Comment: @greeble31 okay! one other question, BufferedReader does not have a read() that reads in a byte array from what I can see. Should I have it read in as a char array or do something else?

Comment: Scratch my last comment. You're right; all you can get out of a `BufferedReader` are chars. The problem is, you needed that `BufferedReader` b/c it supports `readLine()`, but once you start using it, you can't easily get the right `bytes` from the socket anymore. (WHY did they design it that way?) I think the most expedient solution is to ditch the `BufferedReader` entirely, and write your own `readLine` function that assembles strings, one byte at a time, until it hits a '\n'.

Comment: The reason I've never encountered this problem myself is because I send integers in binary format, which means they are a constant size (typically 4 bytes). `DataInputStream` makes that easy, but then you have to worry about endianness and `struct.pack` on the Python side.

Comment: @greeble31 thank you so much for all of your help! I will try that!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by the `BufferedReader` reading in extra data off the line (in order to fill its internal buffer), which makes that data unavailable from `in.read()`.

As you can see from an [sample Android BufferedReader implementation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/d43b9ef/luni/src/main/java/java/io/BufferedReader.java), a call to `readLine()` causes the `BufferedReader` to attempt to fill its internal buffer. It will do this using any available bytes on its source `InputStream`. up to a limit of 8192 chars. And, if the `BufferedReader` has read those bytes, they won't be there when you try to get them from `in.read()`. This throws off your entire size-counting system, meaning you eventually end up blocking in `in.read()`, because you didn't read all the data you expected to.

The most expedient solution is probably to implement your own version of `readLine()`, that assembles strings, one byte at a time, until it hits a '\n'. After all, the only reason you needed a `BufferedReader` was for the `readLine()` function.